# Return @id fields from Spring Data JpaRepository

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I have inherited a MASSIVE Java application and am having quite a few problems trying to find my way around it. I have a specific problem regarding Spring JpaRepository. Please note that I have just started in Spring and am not that sure footed yet.

I have a repository with the @RepositoryRestResource annotations.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface GoodsReceiptRepository extends JpaRepository<GoodsReceipt, GoodsReceiptId> {
```

I have the @Entity as well:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = AvisoPosition.TABLE)
@IdClass(AvisoPositionId.class)
public class AvisoPosition implements Serializable {
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = GoodsReceipt.TABLE)
@IdClass(GoodsReceiptId.class)
public class GoodsReceipt implements Serializable {
```

any fields I have with the @Id annotation are not returned in the JSON response:

```
@Id @Column(name = "LGNTCC")
private String accountingArea;
```

How do I get these ID fields?

If I remove the @Id I get what I want but I do not dare do that as I cannot judge what effect that will have on the application.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah definitely don't remove the `@Id` annotation... JPA needs that to know what define a unique record

Comment: Try just adding `@JsonProperty( "id" )` to those fields...

Comment: Honestly these should probably have been converted to a DTO... Spring might by default ignore @id fields being serialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using `Spring Data Rest` what you're seeing is the default behavior for it.

You can customize this behavior by doing the following:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(YourClassNameGoesHere.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Marcos - thank you, that did it for me. I needed a bit of time to find the correct config file (there are about 10 files that extend RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter) - working now though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a DTO for each entity, then `avisoPostionDTO.setId(avisoPosition.getId());` and you just return the DTO of each entity.

Comment: I would love to do this but I have about 200 @Entity entries in different files, in about 10 projects that I do not know how they work together! I will look into doing this in the future - thanks.